# training a classifier with data within a partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

How can I train a classifier with instances within a partition while its classification algorithm depends on the partition index? For example, suppose the following code snippet:

```
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "path to SVM file")
val r = data.mapPartitionsWithIndex((index,localdata)=>{
  if (index % 2 == 0)
  {
    // train a NaiveBayes with localdata
    NaiveBayes.train(localdata)    // Error => found:iterator[LabeledPoint] , required: RDD[labeledPoint]
  }
  else
  {
    // train a DecisionTree classifier with localdata
    DecisionTree.train(localdata)    // Error => found:iterator[LabeledPoint] , required: RDD[labeledPoint]
  }
})
```

It sounds to me that the error is right, because the tasks are executed within their separated JVM and could not be distributed from a map task. That is why I can not access the SparkContext in my tasks. However, does anyone have an alternate suggestion for doing my purpose?

Comment: Why can't you add partition index to the RDD itself and then divide the single `RDD with index` into `naivebayes rdd` and `decision tree rdd` by adding filter `(index % 2==0)`. You can then apply the repective algorithm on the rdd itself

Comment: You mean that I should append a partition index for each element of my data in my driver program? If yes, how can i get the partition id of each element? Could you please help with a little code snippet?

Comment: Can you please let me know the usecase? Specifically why are you depending on the partition number to choose an algorithm

Comment: I want to design a heterogeneous ensemble classifier that uses distinct learning algorithms for different sections of data. for example, NaiveBayes for partition #1, decision tree for partition #2, SVm for #3 and so on.

Comment: how do you partition your data? any criteria of dividing your rdd partitions?

Comment: I mean how do you make sure that your partition1 data has `type-1` data and partition 2 has `type-2` data

Comment: There are not any criteria. They are distributed evenly in the partitions. for example, considering 1000 instances and 5 partitions, there will be 200 instances per partition and **it does not matter** which type of data is located in partition #1 or #2. I just want to use NaiveBayes for partition #1 and DecisionTree for #2 and so on.

Comment: considering the above example then it's better to sample the `1/5th` portion of the rdd and apply the algorithm, no?

Comment: added my answer based on the discussion

Answer (score 0):

based on the discussion in above comments section - 
you can give a try to this-

```scala
   val rdd = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "path to SVM file")

    // approach -1
    val nb = rdd.sample(withReplacement = false, fraction = 0.5) // sample 50% of the record
    val dt = rdd.sample(withReplacement = false, fraction = 0.5) // sample 50% of the record

    //or approach-2 
    val (nb, dt) = rdd.randomSplit(Array(0.5, 0.5))

    // apply algo
    NaiveBayes.train(nb)
    DecisionTree.train(dt, strategy= ..)
```